# Using the getwd() function in the output_dir parameter for rmarkdown::render (rmarkdown R package) gives unexpected result

Tags: r-markdown

I have this strange scenario in R where the rmarkdown::render() function is performing unexpectedly. Given the following simplistic scripts/test.Rmd

````
---
title: test
---

```{r test}
plot(1:10)
```
````

I then have the following R code:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/projects/test_project"
library('rmarkdown')
rmarkdown::render("scripts/test.Rmd", output_file = 'test.html', output_dir = paste( getwd(), '/', 'reports', sep = '') )
```

This ends up producing output here:

```
/projects/test_project/scripts/reports/test.html
```

Which is unexpected to me because:

```
> paste( getwd(), '/', 'reports', sep = '') )
/projects/test_project/reports
```

I would expected the test.html to be generated here /projects/test_project/reports/test.html. Interestingly, when I forgo the getwd() and use the path as a character string:

```
 > render("scripts/test.Rmd", output_file = 'test.html', output_dir = "/projects/test_project/reports" )
```

This will generate the file in the expected location. Any ideas what is happening here?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] rmarkdown_0.4.2    scales_0.2.4       broom_0.3.5        data.table_1.9.4   gplots_2.15.0      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 reshape2_1.4.1     dplyr_0.3.0.2      ggplot2_1.0.0
[10] stringr_0.6.2      plyr_1.8.1         survival_2.37-7    xtable_1.7-4       fields_7.1         maps_2.3-9         spam_1.0-1         knitr_1.8          argparse_1.0.1
[19] proto_0.3-10       vimcom_1.0-0       setwidth_1.0-3     colorout_1.1-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1     bitops_1.0-6       caTools_1.17.1     chron_2.3-45       colorspace_1.2-4   DBI_0.3.1          digest_0.6.8       evaluate_0.5.5     findpython_1.0.1
[10] formatR_1.0        gdata_2.13.3       getopt_1.20.0      gtable_0.1.2       gtools_3.4.1       htmltools_0.2.6    KernSmooth_2.23-13 lazyeval_0.1.10    magrittr_1.5
[19] MASS_7.3-35        munsell_0.4.2      parallel_3.1.2     psych_1.4.8.11     Rcpp_0.11.3        rjson_0.2.15       tidyr_0.2.0        tools_3.1.2        yaml_2.1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue and feel it might be because of a small bug in the `render()` function. I have raised a issue on its github page:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/416

As a workaround/hack I am using:

```
require(rmarkdown)
fl = render("awesome.Rmd")
file.copy(fl, getwd())
```

Hope that helps.